# Jython: Error in subprocess module, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python'

Tags: java, python, subprocess, jython

I have my project set up like this, it starts in a Java class which uses the PythonInterpreter.initialize method to set my python path to the jython Lib directory and a directory that contains "org/curious/neofelis/*my jython files*".  I then create a PythonInterpreter and have it execute my main jython file.

I guess it's unorthodox but it's been working but when I tried to use Popen I got this error

```
File "/home/steven/jython/Lib/subprocess.py", line 1163, in _get_handles
  elif isinstance(stdout, org.python.core.io.RawIOBase):
```

When trying to reproduce this error I found that I can do this

```
from org.python.util import PythonInterpreter

#A PythonInterpreter running inside a PythonInterpreter!
interpreter = PythonInterpreter()
interpreter.exec("print 3+6");
sys.exit(0)
```

But this didn't fly

```
import org

interpreter = org.python.util.PythonInterpreter()
interpreter.exec("print 3+6");
sys.exit(0)

  File "/home/steven/neofelis/src/main/jython/org/curious/neofelis/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    interpreter = org.python.util.PythonInterpreter()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python'
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing a package -- `org` in this case -- won't always import all its subpackages and submodules.  It is up to the package to define what will be included when you do `import org`.  Obviously, the `python` subpackage is not included in the import by default, so you need to import it explicitly.